# Having issue with URL parameter

Tags: restsharp, restify

I'm trying to read the value pass as URL parameter using restify. The value is passed from C# code that uses RESTsharp. I can see the value in the URL string just fine but when I try to access it I get undefined. It's because request.params does not contain the parameter that I passed. Instead it contains a structure that I passed as request body. What's causing this issue?

```
//Nodejs
server.post('/lab/:id', restify.jsonBodyParser(),myhandle);

function myhandle(req, res, next)
{
    console.log(JSON.strigify(req.params)); //Contains {name:abc}
}


//C# code
........
........
string labstring = "{name:abc}";
request = new RestRequest("lab/123", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("application/json", labstring, ParameterType.RequestBody);

response = RestInterface.Execute(request);
```

UPDATE:
So I tested without jsonbodyparser, and I can read the id. But with jsonbodyparser, I can't. It just a data that I pass as body.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally figured out the problem. Seems that Restify doesn't like using bodyparser with url parameter. When I remove the bodyparser, the url parameter values is stored in params. Otherwise, it contains json structure that I pass as request body. My workaround is to use queryparser and pass the value as query string and access it as req.query.

So my final code looks like this -

```
//Nodejs
server.post('/lab', restify.queryParser(),restify.jsonBodyParser(),myhandle);

function myhandle(req, res, next)
{
   console.log(JSON.strigify(req.query)); //Contains {name:abc}
}
```